# Material UI Drawer that has property "top" disabled

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently trying to use a Persist Left Drawer (Material UI) coming from the left side.  However, I do not want the drawer to span the whole left side of the page.
In other words I want to disable the "top" style property that is shown below.
[.MuiDrawer-paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggUjW.jpg)

What is the best way to make this change?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "makeStyles()" hook to overwrite the default styles of MUI.

https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook

Comment: Thank you for sending that link.  I had tried using the makestyles before but I was using it to overwrite the "Drawer" directly rather than the "Drawer Paper".  It now works thanks.